# PHP float to int cast erratic behavior

Tags: php

At least on my machine:

```
$var = PHP_INT_MAX;
var_dump($var);
$var++;
var_dump((int)$var);
$var += 10;
var_dump((int)$var);
$var += 10000;
var_dump((int)$var);
```

Results:

```
int(9223372036854775807) 
int(-9223372036854775808) 
int(-9223372036854775808) 
int(-9223372036854765568)
```

Why is this behavior so crazy? I could understand it returing PHP_MIN_INT every time, but if you add certain numbers it changes?

I get these results when I run this code here:

http://writecodeonline.com/php/

Comment: You set the variable to the max possible value, then add one to it and expect it to action rationally?

Comment: @the_pete I would expect it to do something consistent. Like reset to zero when it overflows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's undefined, as float doesn't fit in the integer. Anything can happen. It's just PHP, with all its quirks. The operation of casting is implemented using `(long)` cast operation in C, which is undefined in this case, so you shouldn't depend on any particular behavior (in fact, on certain platforms, like MIPS64, this will cause CPU exception, which will stop PHP).

Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.casting.from-float

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED

About last 2 lines I cannot tell, but the negative result is most likely caused by signed integer representation, and arithmetics. Read more about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_%28computer_science%29).

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = PHP_INT_MAX;
var_dump($var);
$var--;
var_dump($var);
$var -= 10;
var_dump((int)$var);
$var -= 10000;
var_dump($var);
```

if we will change + to - code works fine ... it means after maximum value impossible to plus even 1 because memory size is not allocated